# Given $P(A) = 0.9$ and $P(B) = 0.9$, what is a lower bound of $P(A \cup B)$?

Tags: probability

if $P(A) = 0.9$ and $P(B) = 0.9$ what is the lower bound for $P(A \cup B)$?

Comment: What do you have so far? Do you know the formula for the probability of the union of two sets?

Comment: Hint: $P(A)\le P(A\cup B) \ge P(B).$  That gives a *possible* lower bound.  Can it be attained?

Answer (score 3):

My goal in 'this' answer is to supplement with some generalizations for those that are interested in such things.

A rule that is frequently taught in introductory probability is

$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$$

where $A, B$ are two events from some event space $E$. This rule is accounting for potential overlap between events, and a natural way to generalize is to go from two events for a finite number of events. This is given by the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) as applied in probability, which can be expressed as

$$P\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_i\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( (-1)^{k-1}\sum_{I\subseteq\{1,\cdots,n\}\ s.t\ |I|=k}  P(A_I)\right)$$

which expresses that the probability of the union as summing the probabilities of intersections of odd numbers of events and subtracting the probabilities of intersections of even numbers of events for all subsets of the powerset in cardinality up to $n$. This is one of those tools that can seem complicated at first, especially due to verbose notation, but follows a relatively simple pattern.

For calculating bounds, you can consider the [Frechet inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_inequalities):

$$\max \left( 0, \sum_{k=1}^n P(A_k) - (n-1) \right) \leq P\left( \bigcap_{k=1}^{n} A_k \right) \leq \min_k \{ P(A_k) \}$$

$$\max_k \{P(A_k)\} \leq P\left( \bigcup_{k=1}^{n} A_k \right) \leq \min \left(1, \sum_{k=1}^n P(A_k) \right)$$

In the two-event case, we can consider

$$\max \{P(A), P(B)\} \leq P\left( A \cup B \right)$$

which yields (from the OP)

$$\max \{0.9, 0.9\} = 0.9 \leq P\left( A \cup B \right)$$

which agrees with @BruceET's answer.

Comment: This rule overcomplicates the situation.  It suffices to observe that $P(A)\le P(A\cup B)$ to obtain the lower bound immediately. The example $A_1\subset A_2\subset \cdots \subset A_n$ shows this bound is sharp.

Comment: @whuber I agree. ^"*My goal in 'this' answer is to supplement with some generalizations for those that are interested in such things.*"

Answer (score 2):

Comment: I agree with @soakley that you should have shown what you have tried. It seems you need to get more familiar with
the fundamental rules of probability. Such as:

$P(A \cup B) = P(A)+P(B) -P(A\cap B).$

If events $A$ and $B$ are the same, then $P(A\cap B) = P(A) = P(B) = 0.9,$ the smallest possible probability of $P(A\cap B),$ so $P(A\cup B) \ge 0.9.$

Maybe draw a Venn Diagram with events $A$ and $B$ and
imagine the events 'merging', so that the overlap region gets larger and larger--as the union gets ever smaller.
[But be sure to see both of @whuber's Comments.]

Comment: Wouldn't you be looking for the largest possible value of $P(A \cap B)$ instead? Such that $P(A \cup B) \geq P(A) + P(B) - 1 = 0.8$.

Comment: @mhdadk The largest possible value of $P(A \cap B)$ is not $1$, but $0.9$ instead. It is achieved exactly in the same situation, when $A$ and $B$ are the same.

Comment: @Misius I see it now, thanks.